# Jobs are not running on schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

I have a job scheduled to run daily at 10 PM. It was running fine but now, it is not. 
It stopped running on schedule and I need to manually kickoff the job daily.

Jobs are scheduled to run with [sa] account and password has not expired.

I don't understand why this is happening suddenly.

My server is SQL Server 2008 R2. Even I restarted the server couple of days back.
Do I need to install any service pack/hotfix?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, make sure there isn't another job running before that may delay the start off of the job and make sure the algorithm is fcfs.  To debug, set the job to run at a different time, and if it runs successfully there may be another job slightly earlier then 10 causing the error.